# Is there a better more readable way to coalese columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I often need a new column that is the best I can achieve from other columns and I have a specific list of preference priorities.  I am willing to take the first non null value.

```
def coalesce(values):
    not_none = (el for el in values if el is not None)
    return next(not_none, None)

df = pd.DataFrame([{'third':'B','first':'A','second':'C'},
                   {'third':'B','first':None,'second':'C'},
                   {'third':'B','first':None,'second':None},                   
                   {'third':None,'first':None,'second':None},
                   {'third':'B','first':'A','second':None}])

df['combo1'] = df.apply(coalesce, axis=1)
df['combo2'] = df[['second','third','first']].apply(coalesce, axis=1)
print df
```

Results

```
  first second third combo1 combo2
0     A      C     B      A      C
1  None      C     B      C      C
2  None   None     B      B      B
3  None   None  None   None   None
4     A   None     B      A      B
```

this code works (and the result are what I want) but it is not very fast.
I get to pick my priorities if I need to [['second','third','first']]

Coalesce somewhat like the function of the same name from tsql.
I suspect that I may have overlooked an easy way to achieve it with good performance on large DataFrames (+400,000 rows)

I know there are lots of ways to fill in missing data which I often use on axis=0
this is what makes me think I may have missed an easy option for axis=1

Can you suggest something nicer/faster...  or confirm that this is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pd.isnull` to find the null -- in this case `None` -- values:

```
In [169]: pd.isnull(df)
Out[169]: 
   first second  third
0  False  False  False
1   True  False  False
2   True   True  False
3   True   True   True
4  False   True  False
```

and then use `np.argmin` to find the index of the first non-null value. If all the values are null, `np.argmin` returns 0:

```
In [186]: np.argmin(pd.isnull(df).values, axis=1)
Out[186]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 0])
```

Then you could select the desired values from `df` using NumPy integer-indexing:

```
In [193]: df.values[np.arange(len(df)), np.argmin(pd.isnull(df).values, axis=1)]
Out[193]: array(['A', 'C', 'B', None, 'A'], dtype=object)
```

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'third':'B','first':'A','second':'C'},
                   {'third':'B','first':None,'second':'C'},
                   {'third':'B','first':None,'second':None},                   
                   {'third':None,'first':None,'second':None},
                   {'third':'B','first':'A','second':None}])

mask = pd.isnull(df).values
df['combo1'] = df.values[np.arange(len(df)), np.argmin(mask, axis=1)]
order = np.array([1,2,0])
mask = mask[:, order]
df['combo2'] = df.values[np.arange(len(df)), order[np.argmin(mask, axis=1)]]
```

yields

```
  first second third combo1 combo2
0     A      C     B      A      C
1  None      C     B      C      C
2  None   None     B      B      B
3  None   None  None   None   None
4     A   None     B      A      B
```

---

Using argmin instead of `df3.apply(coalesce, ...)` is significantly quicker if the DataFrame has a lot of rows:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df]*1000)

In [230]: %timeit mask = pd.isnull(df2).values; df2.values[np.arange(len(df2)), np.argmin(mask, axis=1)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 617 µs per loop

In [231]: %timeit df2.apply(coalesce, axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 84.1 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 33):

The Pandas equivalent to `COALESCE` is the method `fillna()`:

```
result = column_a.fillna(column_b)
```

The result is a column where each value is taken from `column_a` if that column provides a non-null value, otherwise the value is taken from `column_b`. So your `combo1` can be produced with:

```
df['first'].fillna(df['second']).fillna(df['third'])
```

giving:

```
0       A
1       C
2       B
3    None
4       A
```

And your `combo2` can be produced with:

```
(df['second']).fillna(df['third']).fillna(df['first'])
```

which returns the new column:

```
0       C
1       C
2       B
3    None
4       B
```

If you wanted an efficient operation called `coalesce`, it could simply combine columns with `fillna()` from left to right and then return the result:

```
def coalesce(df, column_names):
    i = iter(column_names)
    column_name = next(i)
    answer = df[column_name]
    for column_name in i:
        answer = answer.fillna(df[column_name])
    return answer

print coalesce(df, ['first', 'second', 'third'])
print coalesce(df, ['second', 'third', 'first'])
```

which gives:

```
0       A
1       C
2       B
3    None
4       A

0       C
1       C
2       B
3    None
4       B
```

Comment: great answer .   .

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'third':'B','first':'A','second':'C'},
                   {'third':'B','first':None,'second':'C'},
                   {'third':'B','first':None,'second':None},                   
                   {'third':None,'first':None,'second':None},
                   {'third':'B','first':'A','second':None}])

df1['combo'] = df1[['second','third','first']].bfill(axis ='columns')["second"]
print(df1)
```

Results

```
  third first second combo
0     B     A      C     C
1     B  None      C     C
2     B  None   None     B
3  None  None   None  None
4     B     A   None     B
```