# Merging differently named Columns into one column, filling the NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

may I please ask help regarding this matter? What is the most pythonic way or easiest way to do this task? I think this could be done with melt or with stack, but I am unable to do it. Your help is much appreciated, Thank you very much.

```
data = [['1',np.nan,np.nan],['2',np.nan,np.nan],[np.nan,'3',np.nan],
        [np.nan,'3',np.nan],[np.nan,'3',np.nan],[np.nan,np.nan,'15'],[np.nan,np.nan,'15']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['no','number', 'numbers'])
df
  no number numbers
0    1    NaN     NaN
1    2    NaN     NaN
2  NaN      3     NaN
3  NaN      3     NaN
4  NaN      3     NaN
5  NaN    NaN      15
6  NaN    NaN      15

Result = [['1'],['2'],['3'],['3'],['3'],['15'],['15']]
Expected = pd.DataFrame(Result, columns = ['NUMBER'])
Expected
 NUMBER
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      3
4      3
5     15
6     15
```

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047277/is-there-a-better-more-readable-way-to-coalese-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and for converting `Series` to one column `DataFrame` function [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = df.stack().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame('NUMBER')
print (df)
  NUMBER
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      3
4      3
5     15
6     15
```

EDIT:

```
data = [['1','100',np.nan],['2',np.nan,np.nan],[np.nan,'3',np.nan],
        [np.nan,'3',np.nan],[np.nan,'3',np.nan],[np.nan,np.nan,'15'],
        [np.nan,np.nan,'15']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['no','number', 'numbers'])
print (df)
    no number numbers
0    1    100     NaN
1    2    NaN     NaN
2  NaN      3     NaN
3  NaN      3     NaN
4  NaN      3     NaN
5  NaN    NaN      15
6  NaN    NaN      15
```

If want first non numeric value per rows:

```
df1 = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].to_frame('NUMBER')
print (df1)
  NUMBER
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      3
4      3
5     15
6     15
```

If need all non numeric values:

```
df2 = df.stack().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame('NUMBER')
print (df2)
  NUMBER
0      1
1    100
2      2
3      3
4      3
5      3
6     15
7     15
```

Comment: oh wow. I was under my nose the entire time. Maybe I should take a break and stop over complicating things. Thanks!